# Why does power supplied by battery decreases when resistance is increased?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, resistance

Consider a simple circuit with 5V battery and a 5 ohm resistor. In this circuit the power supplied by the battery is 5 watt. Now if I increase the resistance to 10 ohm the power supplied by the battery will reduce to 2.5 watt.

Why didn't the power supplied remain constant? Can anyone give me an intuitive reason behind this decrease?

Comment: There is a fundamental relationship between the Voltage, Current and Power in a series circuit using direct current, This relationship was first described by Georg Ohm in 1827. In 1879 James Clerk Maxwell published the mathematical description of the physics involved. There are inadequate analogies using water flow but an intuitive reason for why electrons flow in conductor may be impossible as electron behavior cannot be directly observed. (Werner Heisenberg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitive?  No math?

The first rule is:  electric current is not a flow of energy.   Also, the voltage is not a flow of energy.

Instead, electric current is more like a drive-belt running across pulleys.  The path for electric current is always in a complete closed circle.  Notice that the same electric current going into a load is also coming back out of the load.  An amp goes into your resistors or light bulbs, and exactly an amp comes back out.  And if your power supply is a battery, then the path for current is *through* the battery and back out again via the other terminal.  Batteries don't "supply" any current, and resistors don't "consume" any.  Circuits really are complete circles: they're like "electricity flywheels."

(To extract energy from a spinning flywheel, just rub your thumb on the rim.  The entire flywheel slows down as one.)

Yet while current goes in a closed circle, the *electrical energy* comes out of the five-volt power supply, races to the distant load, and then gets turned into heat (or light, or mechanical work, etc.)  The path for energy is one-way.  Electrical energy *doesn't* flow in a circle.  Instead, the energy *goes down both wires* as it travels to the load resistor.

(Beware of the misconception that says the energy sticks to each electron, where the electrons move like little train-cars delivering coal.  Nope.  Bill Nye and Mrs. Frizzel were lying to you!  Heh.  Instead, the electrons go slooowwwly in a circle, while the energy races almost instantly from power-supply to load-resistor.  The energy is a type of wave-energy.  The electrons are the "medium" for the moving waves.)

Next:  notice that the bit of electrical energy can be composed of high voltage at low current, or also made of low voltage at high current.   Your five watts of energy-flow could be created by one volt at five amps, or by five volts at one amps.  Same energy-flow, but completely different volts and amperes.

This same concept appears everywhere in machines.   A drive-belt can deliver one horsepower by moving slowly at high tension, or instead by moving very fast with low, loose tension.  The force delivered by the belt is not a flow of energy.  Neither is the speed of the belt a flow of energy.  But together, speed times tension, that tells us the amount of energy-flow being transported by the drive belt.

And, something similar happens with drive-shafts, where the torque-force of the shaft is not a flow of energy, and neither are the shaft-RPMs a flow of energy.  Yet with both torque and RPM together, energy is flowing along the drive-shaft.

Or maybe you wanted the Hydraulic analogy, where water is pumped around a closed loop of hose?  In that case, if we want to know the energy-flow that goes from the pump to the hydraulic load, we must multiply the pump-pressure times the water speed (the water flow-rate.)

Circuits also have the "two things" found in machines.

Electric current is like a flywheel: a lot of motion, but zero watts of energy flow.

Electric voltage is like a stretched belt, or like a twisted rod: immense forces, but zero watts of energy flow.

To produce a flow of energy, we need two things together.  Torque and RPM of the shaft?  How about electric fields (the voltage) and magnetic fields (the current?)   In electric circuits, the energy-flow is completely made up of EM, of electromagnetism.  It's basically the same thing as radio waves: electric and magnetic fields at 90deg orientation.  The basic reason that watts equal volts x amps is because watts in circuits is an electromagnetic energy flow, and because the voltage tells us the e-field pattern, and the current tells us the b-field pattern.

Heh, a flashlight circuit, that's basically a zero-frequency RF transmission line, with lightspeed "radiation" pouring out of the battery, racing along the pair of wires, and being absorbed by the light bulb.

ANSWER: Flywheel analogy: if we force a bike-wheel to spin, but then rub on the tire so it stalls, the energy-flow is zero.  The rubber is the electrons, the rim-torque is the voltage, and the RPM is the current.  If the drive-force on the wheel is constant, then the more friction, the less energy-flow, in direct proportion.  (Double the friction, the tire slows down, and we cut the energy-flow in half.)  Notice that for this analogy, we'd need a constant-force to spin the wheel.  Perhaps wrap a long string around the rim, and hang a heavy weight on the end.  That gives a "constant force flywheel," like a constant-voltage power supply.  To turn off the flywheel, just use a brake to solidly grab the rim.  That "breaks the circuit" by adding a small piece of insulator to the tire.  "Insulating gap" means that, a constant force is applied to the rubber-circuit, but the rubber in one small section cannot flow.  Therefore the entire wheel remains still.  (And in that case, a short circuit is a bike wheel with a heavy rim-weight but no frictional load.  It's damaged by destructive overspeed.)

.

[image]

Above is our "electricity flywheel,"  with a constant friction-spot on the lowerr right, and a constant-force driver on the upper left.

In EM terms, the two wires of a circuit form the two plates of a capacitor.  At the sane tinme, the single loop of the circuit forms the single turn of an inductor.  Put them together, and we create an electromagnetic energy flow, going one way along both wires: from the battery to the resistor.

It's also like a slow-turning bicycle-wheel, where your thumb is rubbing on the rim (the resistor,) while elsewhere your hand is speeding up the wheel.  The moving tire is like electric current, while the stretched/compressed rubber (it has a tension-difference) is like the voltage.

Here's a diagram from the JD Kraus textbook ELECTROMAGNETICS, showing the DC energy flow of a simple battery circuit.  The energy travels via the surrounding EM fields, going in the same direction along both wires.  (Only the electrons are moving in a closed-circle path.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Battery is a contant voltage source. It is not a constant power source.

You can use these basic formulas:
U=R×I
P=U×I
and you get:
P=U×U/R

As you can see, delivered power is dependant on load resistance. The higher load resistance results in the lower delivered power.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone give me an intuitive reason behind this decrease?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8rSl5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Original circuit. (b) Equivalent circuit. (c) The circuit split in two halves.*

Since the total power in each of the circuits (a), (b) and (c) remains the same then each of the half-cicuits in (c) must use half the power of (a).

Answer (score 1):

Doubling the resistance halved the current.

Then power is current squared times the resistance.

So you multiplied the resistance by two

And

Divided the current by two

So as the current is squared that reduces the result.

Put it in a spreadsheet and keep changing the resistance...